# java mongodb connection using ssh and ssl

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, ssh

I am trying to connect to mongodb over ssh and ssl in java. I had a single CA.PEM file and I am able to connect to mongodb via mongodb compass client. I am not sure how to connect from java. Any help on this would be great, thanks.

Comment: I tried importing ca.pem into cacerts getting following stack trace:com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@3007f806. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=localhost:27020, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake}, caused by {java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}}]

Comment: my .pem file contains two certificates (2 --begin-- --end--)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB Atlas version, you will be able to connect from Java using MongoDB connection string

for MongoDB Atlas, connection string looks like

```
mongodb+srv://<user-name>:<password>@<server-name>.mongodb.net/
```

Comment: I am using mongo-java-driver to connect.

Comment: I am able to do the connection to mongo db using connection string. but unable to do with ssh and ssl.